# c# - XAML: how to open an menu with textbox and button by button click?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to open an rectangular box menu with textbox and button, when the button in appbar pressed. Let me explain my question again.

I want to have search option in my app. so, i have search icon in my app bar. when user wants to search he swipes up the app bar and press search icon.

When the search icon is pressed, a menu with rectangular box contains textbox & button, should be opened.

I dunno how to code for this in C# and XAML. please help me. Every answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CustomMessageBox` from [WP toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) and insert a `Textbox` in it

```
TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.Width = 460;
txtBox.Text = selectedChild.Name;
txtBox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
txtBox.MaxLength = 14;


CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox();
messageBox.Caption = "hello";
messageBox.Content = txtBox;
messageBox.LeftButtonContent = "OK";
messageBox.RightButtonContent = "Cancel";
messageBox.IsFullScreen = false;
messageBox.Dismissed += MessageBoxDismissed;
messageBox.Show();
```

here is the callback

```
private void MessageBoxDismissed(object sender, DismissedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomMessageBox messageBox = sender as CustomMessageBox;
    if (messageBox != null && e.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton)
    {
        TextBox tb = messageBox.Content as TextBox;
        if (tb != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text.Trim()))
        {
           //do your stuff
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you have to install wptoolkit. And here is the [instruction](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit)

Comment: I installed everything form NuGet. thanks for the NuGet idea. NuGet, Works well. But your code doesn't

Comment: It is working in my case. I called the above code in a button event

Answer (score 0):

The Perfect answer for this question is use to NuGet. you can download it from [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

And you can the code to initialize the textbox in CustomMessageBox by clicking the following link:
[display two textbox in customMessageBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223977/display-two-textbox-in-custommessagebox)