# display two textbox in customMessageBox?

Tags: c#, messagebox

Well, I want to display two text boxes next to next in `customMessageBox`. So i have coded for two Text Boxes. like below. I named `soora` and `ayath` for it. But in `customMessageBox`, i cannot call two text boxes in the same time. It shows error. How to display two text boxes next to next in `customMessageBox`. I only the error and it is form `Content = soora + ayath`

My C# CODE;

```
TextBox soora = new TextBox();
                soora.Height = 72;
                soora.Width = 150;
                soora.MaxLength = 3;

TextBox ayath = new TextBox();
                ayath.Height = 72;
                ayath.Width = 150;
                ayath.MaxLength = 3;

CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
            {
                Title = "GO TO",
                Content = soora + ayath,
                RightButtonContent = "Go !",
            };
```

Comment: What did you expect to get when you added textbox to textbox? A richtextbox? That operation is not allowed. And also, show us the deffinition of Content (the type of) and CustomMessageBox.

Comment: i need to get input form user. i need two input fields in MessageBox

Comment: can you show the Implementation of `CustomMessageBox`? what is `Content`?

Comment: i have installed `NuGet` from [here](https://www.nuget.org/) and using customMessageBox from that only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a `container control` to hold both `textboxes`

```
TextBox soora = new TextBox();
                soora.Height = 72;
                soora.Width = 150;
                soora.MaxLength = 3;

TextBox ayath = new TextBox();
                ayath.Height = 72;
                ayath.Width = 150;
                ayath.MaxLength = 3;

StackPanel container = new StackPanel{
                           Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal
                       };

container.Children.Add(soora);
container.Children.Add(ayath);    

CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
            {
                Title = "GO TO",
                Content = container,
                RightButtonContent = "Go !",
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

if  you want to display text then

```
Content = soora.Text + ayath.Text,
```

Comment: i need to get input form user. i need two input fields in MessageBox